# Proof on permutations with Coq proof assistant

Tags: permutation, coq

I am working on permutations on Coq, defined as follows:

`Definition Tperm := list (nat* nat).`

I have an `act` function of type `Tperm -> nat -> nat` that returns the image of the natural passed in parameter by the permutation.
I also have an `atoms` function of type `Tperm -> list(nat)` that returns all the naturals that are modified by the permutation.

So now, I have to prove that lemma: `Lemma act_atoms: forall pi a, ~act(pi)(a) = a -> In a (atoms(pi)).`

I have started a proof by induction on pi, but am stuck after proving the first subgoal. Any help would be appreciated. Below are the definitions of act and atoms.

```
Fixpoint act (t : Tperm) (i : nat) : nat := match t with
|nil => i
|cons(k,l) p => if(beq_nat(act p i) k) then l
                  else if(beq_nat(act p i) l) then k
                  else act p i
end.

Fixpoint atoms (t : Tperm) : list(nat) :=
match t with
  |nil => nil
  |cons(k,l) nil => cons k (cons l nil)
  |cons(k,l) p => cons k (atoms p)
end.
```

Comment: It is difficult to help without having the full definitions for atoms and in particular, act. Note too that your definition for Tperm is quite weak, there are many elements in `Tperm` that are not permutations. Also, you may want to study some other libraries on permutations, and use an effective notion of list membership, etc....

Comment: But roughly, in the second inductive case, you'll need to check whether the current atom was affected by the induction hypothese or not. If not, then it must be the case. This is hard to do in the standard library due to decidability conditions getting in the way, with some other libraries such as mathcomp you would have a better time I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback about Tperm. I guess I am supposing all of the lists I will use are well formed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof. Note that I dont't recommend fomalizing permutations that way.

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.PeanoNat Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Definition tperm := list (nat * nat).

Fixpoint act (pi : tperm) (a : nat) :=
  match pi with
  | (i,s) :: r => if Nat.eqb i a then s else
                  if Nat.eqb s a then i else act r a
  | []         => a
  end.

Definition atoms (pi : tperm) := concat (map (fun p => [fst p; snd p]) pi).

Lemma act_atoms pi a : act pi a <> a -> In a (atoms pi).
Proof.
induction pi as [| [i s] pi ihpi]; simpl.
+ now auto.
+ now destruct (Nat.eqb_spec i a); destruct (Nat.eqb_spec s a); auto.
Qed.
```

As you know, the first case is trivial. Secondly, we have to do case analysis on whether the atom is equal to the current element of the permutation `i =? a`. A very efficient way to do such case analysis is to use a "reflection" lemma.

- It that is the case, the proof is trivial.
- Otherwise, we conclude by using the induction hypothesis.